# Pasting bash script to console without exit calls

Tags: bash

I often "debug" bash scripts by opening them in the text editor and pasting them to the console, not line by line but "logical unit by logical unit".

Sometimes I then have these constructs:

```
if [ ! -f $inputFile ]; then
    echo "You must specify an existing file, milord!"
    exit 5
fi
```

However, pasting that to the console (without a valid `$inputFile` of course) immediately closes my console.

Is there any way to circumvent that?

Comment: [trap](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html)

Comment: Maybe this could help you: [how to trap errors inside the if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103701/how-to-trap-errors-inside-the-if-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One hack you could try would be to just make exit an alias:

```
alias exit='echo exiting...'
```

Your sample code now will just print `exiting...` and move on.

When you're done with your debugging session, you need to just:

```
unalias exit
```

Comment: One problem with this is that the code may continue running after where it normally would have exited. So be careful!

Comment: @GordonDavisson correct, thanks for pointing that out.